# With Spark/Scala, is there a way to join with complex data structures?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have a data frame with a complex structure.  Down inside that structure, I need to replace a value with another based on a mapping from another data frame.  We currently accomplish this by exploding the data frame, joining, and then doing a grouping with aggregation.  The problem is we are turning 3.5B records in 210B records.  The cost of the grouping is very high.  And I'm starting with data that is already grouped as I want it.  Is there was some way to accomplish this without doing the explode and grouping?

Here is some example code from a Zeppelin notebook to illustrate our current method:

```
import spark.implicits._

case class A(device_id: Long, cluster: Seq[B])
case class B(location_id: Long, score: Double)
case class C(location_id: Long, location_key: String)
case class D(location_key: String, score: Double)

val df1 = Seq(
  A(1L, Seq(B(1L, 1.1), B(2L, 2.2), B(3L, 3.3))),
  A(2L, Seq(B(4L, 4.4), B(5L, 5.5), B(6L, 6.6))),
  A(3L, Seq(B(7L, 7.7), B(8L, 8.8), B(9L, 9.9)))
).toDF

val df2 = Seq(
  C(1L, "a"),
  C(2L, "b"),
  C(3L, "c"),
  C(4L, "d"),
  C(5L, "e"),
  C(6L, "f"),
  C(7L, "g"),
  C(8L, "h"),
  C(9L, "i")
).toDF

val df3 = df1
  .select($"device_id", explode($"cluster").as("record"))
  .select($"device_id", $"record.location_id".as("location_id"), $"record.score".as("score"))

val df4 = df3
  .join(df2, "location_id")
  .select($"device_id", $"location_key", $"score")

val df5 = df4
  .groupBy($"device_id")
  .agg(
    collect_list(struct($"location_key", $"score")).as("cluster")
  )

df1.printSchema()
df1.show(3, false)

df5.printSchema()
df5.show(3, false)
```

The output looks like this:

```
root
 |-- device_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- cluster: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- location_id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = false)

+---------+------------------------------+
|device_id|cluster                       |
+---------+------------------------------+
|1        |[[1, 1.1], [2, 2.2], [3, 3.3]]|
|2        |[[4, 4.4], [5, 5.5], [6, 6.6]]|
|3        |[[7, 7.7], [8, 8.8], [9, 9.9]]|
+---------+------------------------------+

root
 |-- device_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- cluster: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- location_key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)

+---------+------------------------------+
|device_id|cluster                       |
+---------+------------------------------+
|1        |[[a, 1.1], [c, 3.3], [b, 2.2]]|
|2        |[[e, 5.5], [d, 4.4], [f, 6.6]]|
|3        |[[g, 7.7], [h, 8.8], [i, 9.9]]|
+---------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a solution.  At least not one that worked for me.  I tried converting `df` into a dataset and mapping over that.  Inside the map I tried to create a dataframe, do the join, collect, and return new case class.  This doesn't work.  The only thing that worked was converting `df2` into a Scala map, and then doing a map over the dataset, where I could lookup the replacement value in the map.  The problem is my real life `df2` is too big to fit into driver memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this help you on the performance problem let alone answer your question. But the explode step could be changed to use a flatMap which might increase your performance a little (although I think explode and flatMap should be quite similar under the hood so a performance difference could also be nonexistent):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession                                                                                                  
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ collect_list, struct}                                                                             

case class A(device_id: Long, cluster: Seq[B])                                                                                            
case class B(location_id: Long, score: Double)                                                                                            
case class C(location_id: Long, location_key: String)                                                                                     
case class D(location_key: String, score: Double)                                                                                         
case class E(device_id: Long, location_id: Long, score: Double)                                                                           

object ComplexDataStructures {                                                                                                            
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {                                                                                                 

    val spark = SparkSession                                                                                                              
      .builder()                                                                                                                          
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")                                                                                                 
      .config("spark.master", "local")                                                                                                    
      .getOrCreate()                                                                                                                      

    import spark.implicits._                                                                                                              

    val df1 = Seq(                                                                                                                        
      A(1L, Seq(B(1L, 1.1), B(2L, 2.2), B(3L, 3.3))),                                                                                     
      A(2L, Seq(B(4L, 4.4), B(5L, 5.5), B(6L, 6.6))),                                                                                     
      A(3L, Seq(B(7L, 7.7), B(8L, 8.8), B(9L, 9.9)))                                                                                      
    ).toDS.as[A]                                                                                                                          

    val df2 = Seq(                                                                                                                        
      C(1L, "a"),                                                                                                                         
      C(2L, "b"),                                                                                                                         
      C(3L, "c"),                                                                                                                         
      C(4L, "d"),                                                                                                                         
      C(5L, "e"),                                                                                                                         
      C(6L, "f"),                                                                                                                         
      C(7L, "g"),                                                                                                                         
      C(8L, "h"),                                                                                                                         
      C(9L, "i")                                                                                                                          
    ).toDS.as[C]                                                                                                                          


    val df3 = df1.flatMap{ case A(a,b) => b.map((a,_)).map( x => E(x._1, x._2.location_id, x._2.score)) }                                 

    val df4 = df3.join(df2, df3("location_id") === df2("location_id")).select(df3("device_id"), df2("location_key"), df3("score"))        

    val df5 = df4.groupBy("device_id").agg(collect_list(struct("location_key","score")).as("cluster"))                                    

    df5.printSchema()                                                                                                                     
    df5.show(3, false)                                                                                                                    

  }                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input.  I don't think that will accomplish what I need.  I think the flatMap is doing basically the same thing as explode.  Mostly because you still have to do the groupBy, and that is what's taking a day to run on our system.  We may have an issue with shuffle partitions as well, but haven't gotten that far.